# Setting "related" just to one product

Tags: related-products

Is it posible to set, for example related product:

I set "product_2" as a related product when managing "product_1". Now on frontend when I visit the "product_1" page I can see "product_2" in the blok "Related products".

Is is posible to see "product_1" as a related product when I visit "product_2" page? Or is it obligatory to set it in the administration.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, related products are not automatically set to each other when applied.

Thus, apart from using a module, you will have to set the related products for both products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you maybe know, is there a free module for this online?

Comment: @NicoleOlsen I'm not aware of any free module doing this unfortunately